# Best way to create repeating image from existing one

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

Given two different image types:

1. A regular pattern (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAEao.jpg)
2. A plain image, that doesnt repeat (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUpai.jpg)

to 1) How do you extract the smallest existing pattern in the image

I currently crop it, save it and check in the browser if it repeats correctly - but thats really time-consuming / also really difficult with complex patterns

to 2) How do you make the image repeat?

I currently do it in two different ways: either put a small gradient on all 4 sides, which only works on some images and the transition doesnt really look that good, or the complex way: Have the original image in the center with a padding of ~200px to each side, copy the image to all sides (bordering the centered image), select the transitions and fill it with "content sensitive fill", and crop it again to the original image dimensions - repeats fine/looks good, but again,  thats really time-consuming

---

I use Photoshop; the images are for website backgrounds

sry for my expressions/technical terms, but english isnt my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop, using Filter > Other > Offset can help with seamless tiles and textures. Put in values for horizontal and vertical that are half the size of the texture you're trying to make into a tile.

Comment: wow. nice.. that filter looks just what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

That is called a seamless texture. There is no quick way to do it. The least time consuming way of doing it is to grab one that already exists :)

But if you need to do it with your texture, I personally like grabbing half the image, put in a new layer and move it to the other side, so right and left corners are touching on the middle of the frame (that means the original middle of the image is on both sides and already fits seamlessly). If it's particularly hard (like the one you want to do) I usually feather the border of one side and move on top of the other so it blends a little better. After that I start adjusting one of them using distort, warp and smudge until I get both sides aligned.

Keep in mind that you'll have to do the same job on the upper and lower side of the image as well, if you want to tile it both ways.